# Span does not recognize a parent element - Overlapping

Tags: html, css, sass

First of all, thank you for taking your time answering my maybe stupid question. I have a problem with my span not wanting to stay where mummy told him to stay.

HTML

```
<section class="row" id="white_background">
   <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                <article class="news_post">
                    <span class='news_head'>
                        <h4>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</h4>
                        <p><?php echo $NewsItem->getValueEncoded( "summary" ) ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $NewsItem->getValueEncoded( "uploadDate" ) ?></p>
                    </span>
                </article>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Sass

```
#white_background {
background: $light;
height:100%;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
@inlcude clearfix;
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: $purple;
   }
}

.news_post {
@include article_back (
    '../img/picture_2.png');
padding: 20px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.news_head {
max-width:  330px;
background-color:   $purple;
padding: 6px 12px;
display: block;
color: $white;
margin: auto  50px auto 0px;
transform: translateY(120px);
text-align: left;
font-size: 12px;

    h4 {
        font-family: $heading;
        font-size:13px;
        }

}
```

Now it does this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlhI8.jpg

So it seems like the span does not see the div as a boundary.. any ideas?^^

**EDIT**: Sorry for making a slight mess here. 
What I want to achieve is make the article-span overflow the article in a controlled way. Meaning: If I *manually* resize the window, the **span** should ***not*** go outside of the parent **article.**

The problem is that the sections I used, do not render the movement of the span properly and that is why the sections overlaps, like shown here: [http://imgur.com/a/fZyux](https://imgur.com/a/fZyux) (Note: the left item in the purple box overflows the light grey edges of the article. It should stay inside this grey box.

The dealbreaker now is, when i resize the window to smaller window sizes, the span starts to move down, but i expected it to move to the edge of it's parten article or div.
The span does not get recognize that it sits in a div and does not get restricted by its boundaries. Why is that the case? It's super hard to explain but I tried. 
Take a look at the full mockup to get an idea. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDyY1.jpg

I hope this makes it more clear what i want to achieve^^

Comment: you have a typo in `@inlcude clearfix;`  If that doesn't fix anything, could you put this in a fiddle and let us know what you expect it to look like?

Comment: @andi i have it on a server up and running ^^ and you could check out the problem.. i also have screenshots http://imgur.com/a/ifHdu

Comment: What is the desired result? Right now all we know is you don't like what you're getting. Your answer should include a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Screenshots don't provide code, which is what is required to provided solutions. **P.S.** a `<span>` shouldn't contain block level elements. Use a block level element to contain block level elements.

Comment: what is your server URL?

Comment: Please also read [ask], especially the part about how to write a title. That title doesn't help anyone know what's going on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8pd7pbaL/3/ sorry for the backgrounds.. but what it basically does is overflowing to the next section which it shouldnt do. also @andi you can see it at http://134.255.234.196/school/3.2/REthink/ Resize the news part and he how the box is going outside of the div for wahtever reason

Comment: Instead of using translateY to push the blue boxes down, just give them a margin-top.  Then they'll stay within their parent.

Comment: @andi yes now it stays, but generall i want it to stay in the section like so : http://imgur.com/a/nnVH6 not within the article

Comment: so do you want to just push the text within the lower section down by 120px, then?

Comment: @hungerstar i will from know on remember that and edit my main post

Comment: @andi check the initial post, i edited everything to make it more clear

Comment: Before anything else, your HTML is invalid. Fix your HTML and then edit your question to reflect your changes. This may be the cause of your issue in the first place. `<span>` for example may not contain most of the elements you are using.

Comment: @Rob What exactly is invalid? What would you use instead of span?

Comment: I already said. `<span>` is for inline phrasing content. None of the elements you use are phrasing content and are block level to boot. Possibly a `<div>` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Rob too bad changing it to div didnt change anything at all. Would you need to put appropriate CSS on that div aswell? it's still the same class

Comment: There's a typo in one of your@include

Comment: @Rob fixed that. Also the main problem is, if the news gets bigger (the text in the purple box) it also goes outside of the div instead of being blocked. So i did: changed <span> to <div> put more text in to see if it still goes out of the parent article.

Comment: Personally I would try to use a negative margin `.news_head`, [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/n47czqyL/1). How do you plan to handle varying amounts of content? As you can see from my example the containing elements have a different height.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display flex;`.

```css
article {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
article span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <span></span>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sections overlap because using:

```
transform: translateY(120px);
```

makes the element behave like it was:

```
position: relative;
top: 120px;
```

The element has moved on the screen, but the rest of the layout renders as if it was still in the original place. To push the borders you can add `margin-bottom` to your `span`.

```css
.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: auto;
}
.element-transformed {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateY(70px);
}
.element-positioned {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
}
.make-some-space {
  height: 100px;
}
.element-transformed-with-margin {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateY(70px);
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="element-transformed">
    <p>transform: translateY(70px);</p>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="element-positioned">
    <p>position: relative; top: 70px;</p>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="make-some-space"></div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="element-transformed-with-margin">
    <p>transform: translateY(70px); margin-bottom: 70px;</p>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="element-positioned">
    <p>position: relative; top: 70px;</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just like the question, your HTML is invalid. A span cannot contain those elements.